# Python FTP download file that has spaces in the filename

Tags: python, ftp, python-2.x, ftplib

Last week our supplier of measurement devices updates the Firmware. 
I use here always a python script to download all `.rd` files.

Formally the firmware returned the filenames always like `191222_221400.rd`
One complete filename.

Unfortunately after the update the firmware is giving it back as `"rw group owner oct 9_191222_221400.rd"`

Where the script now is stopping to write. And then not deleting it.

```
## Handles to download and delete the .rd file in the project folder
def downloadAndDelet_RD(self):
    time.sleep(5)
    files = []
    #print self.conf.INSipAddress
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(self.conf.INSipAddress)
    ftp.login()
    files =  ftp.nlst()
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".rd"):
            #print self.conf.newP + '//'  + self.conf.nativefolderName + '//' +self.gpsSelectedProject+"//"+f
            ftpfile = urllib2.urlopen("ftp://"+self.conf.INSipAddress +"//"+f)
            localfile = open(self.conf.newP + '//'  + self.conf.nativefolderName + '//' +self.gpsSelectedProject+"//"+f, "wb")        
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % f, localfile.write)
            localfile.close()
            if self.conf.INSDeleteRD == 1:
                ftp.delete(f)
```

I have tried all kind of things to let it accept the whole name, but I am stuck. And not getting anywhere.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: You're using Python 2, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct Python 2

Comment: Does the code throw any errors? It just runs successfully, but the output file is empty?

Comment: That is the problem, there are no errors, it just "hangs". It starts the download. Where it gets the name, but no further the 0KB and the name.

Comment: Do you know where it hangs?

Comment: Do you mean that you get the `rw ... 9_191222_221400.rd` back in the `nlst` call? But that actual file name is what? Only the `9_191222_221400.rd`?

Comment: Yes, I get the complete name back, rw ... 9_191222_221400.rd

Comment: Downloading by Filezilla is no problem at all.

Comment: you mean the filezilla logfile?

Comment: Yes, FileZilla log file (a real log file, not the message log from FileZilla GUI). + How does FileZilla show the filename? As `rw ... 9_191222_221400.rd` or `9_191222_221400.rd`?

Comment: FileZilla download it normal

Comment: From filezilla I get normal "191223_221004.rd" no problem. From script I get "-rw-r--r-- 1 owner group       1483776 Oct 9 1999 191223_221004.rd"

Comment: Does my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

*You didn't provide the information I have asked for. Anyway, based on the intfomation we have:*

Your FTP server seems to be broken, it returns a complete directory listing, including metadata in the `NLST` response. That violates FTP specification. I do not think there's anything wrong with your code. You will have to workaround the bug by stripping the metadata from the `NLST` response.

```
f = f.split()[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Python 2x in my life.  I got to the game kind of late, so I have always used Python 3x.  The script below works fine for me in Python 3x.

```
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP()
from datetime import datetime


filenames = []
data = []

ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.anything.com', 'u_name', 'ps_wd')  


def get_dirs_ftp(folder=""):
    contents = ftp.nlst(folder)
    folders = []
    for item in contents:
        if "." not in item:
            folders.append(item)
    return folders
def get_all_dirs_ftp(folder=""):
    dirs = []
    new_dirs = []
    new_dirs = get_dirs_ftp(folder)
    while len(new_dirs) > 0:
        for dir in new_dirs:
            dirs.append(dir)

        old_dirs = new_dirs[:]
        new_dirs = []
        for dir in old_dirs:
            for new_dir in get_dirs_ftp(dir):
                new_dirs.append(new_dir)
    dirs.sort()
    return dirs

#allfiles = []
# get parent and child folders in directory
all_dirs = get_all_dirs_ftp()

# create a list to append metadata
dir_list = []

for dir in all_dirs:
    ftp.cwd('/'+dir+'/')
    print(dir)
    dir_list.append(dir)
    ftp.dir(dir_list.append)

    len(dir_list)


# you probably want to dump the results to a file...
outF = open('C:/your_path/filenames.csv', 'w')
for line in dir_list:
  # write line to output file
  outF.write(line)
  outF.write("\n")
outF.close()
print('Done!!')
```